# Dog with soft mucusy poop

Tags: dogs

Our dog recently pooped on the stairs which is very unlike her. This was on Friday and it was very soft and brown.

This past weekend her poop has still been soft and now has a tinge of green to it. Should we be worried? Anything we should check her for?

She is very much herself still,  playing, eating, no vomiting. We do go on regular walks but otherwise she stays in our fenced yard or inside.  Recently we did cut down a tree in our yard so perhaps something related to that?

She is a 1 year 2 months old Goldendoodle.

Answer (score 3):

She could have eaten something wrong or maybe got an infection. As long as her behavior stays normal, you should keep an eye on her, but you don't have to rush to the vet.

Make sure that:

- She has ample clean drinking water. If she refuses to drink for 24 hours, go see a vet.
- She eats at least half of her daily meal. If she doesn't eat anything for 36 hours, go see a vet.
- She passes stool regularily. If she doesn't poop within 24 hours, go see a vet.
- There is nothing poisenous in her yard that she could swallow. If you're concerned about the tree trunk, cover it with a bucket or tarp.
- You don't feed her anything unusual. Certain foods that are eadible for humans can be harmful for dogs, like chocolate, raisins, garlic, onion and certain brands of yoghurt.

If this was caused by ingesting something wrong, it should be gone in a day or two. If this is an infection, it can take a week to be completely cured. If her condition worsens, she starts shivering at room temperature, becomes lethargic or her stool becomes liquid or slimy, please see a vet immediately.

In case it is an infection, please don't let her play with other dogs until 5 days **after** her stool returned to the normal consistency and clean up any poop she drops during walks. That way you avoid infecting other dogs as well.